# Comma with 3 digit and also apply decimal with two digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Comma with 3 digit and also apply decimal with two digit.

This will apply in Key-press.
Ex.

```
**input** => **Output**

    55 => 55
    55.0 => 55.0
    55.00 => 55.00
    355.01 => 355.01
    4555.01 => 4,555.01
```

Could not be type 3 digits decimal value

Could any one please suggest that how can we do in jquery or any JS ?

Comment: regex most likely

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: @Sarath, This is not what i needed.